# How do to install geckodriver and chromedriver to your local environment

Tags: django, vagrant, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework, geckodriver

I am setting up Robot Framework within the same code base as a django app. When I run my sample test case I get the error:

`WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.`

`WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.`

All of this is happening with a vagrant shell with pip system package installed. I'm a newbie and am trying to build in someone elses code so I'm not sure on how the files used to set up the local environment do.

I first tried to installing geckodriver while in the virtual environment by running: `pip install geckodriver`. Fro that I get this error:

`(vagrant) vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32:/vagrant$ pip install geckodriver 
Collecting geckodriver

     Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement geckodriver (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for geckodriver`

Next tried I've downloaded the executable and placed it in the repository. But I don't know how to point to the executable to have it installed. How would I put the executable 'In Path' and run the executables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you need to install Geckodriver: this [AskUbuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/a/871077) has the high level steps for the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Try these Steps:

1- Go to the geckodriver releases page. Find the latest version of the driver for your platform and download it.

2- Extract the file and make it executable

3- Add the driver to your PATH so other tools can find it or you can add the one line script in your test script as well.For example :

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\Selenium\geckodriver-v0.19.1-win64\geckodriver.exe");